# How do I figure out which of my imports are from in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have a bunch of imports in my package and [need to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52743028/656912) sort out which ones are coming from a specific package (MissingH). I'm not sure how to do this other than by searching for each on Hoogle. Is there a way to do this programmatically or at the command line by just scanning my package's files?

Here's my list of imports (from all files of [my package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/crypto-enigma)):

```
import           Control.Arrow
import           Control.Exception      (assert)
import           Control.Monad          (unless)
import           Control.Monad.Except
import           Control.Monad.Zip
import           Control.Applicative
import           Data.Monoid
import           Data.List
import           Data.List.Split        (splitOn)
import qualified Data.Map               as M
import           Data.Maybe
import           Text.Printf            (printf)
import           Data.Char              (toUpper)
import           Data.String.Utils      (replace)

import Data.Char (chr, ord)
import Data.List (sort)

import Control.Applicative
import Data.Monoid
import Data.Char
import Data.List
import Data.List.Split          (chunksOf)
import Data.String.Utils        (replace)
import Text.Printf              (printf)
```

Comment: Potential close voters: this clearly isn't a "recommendation" question. The "is there a way" phrase is a poor indicator for "off-topic/recommendation".

Comment: @DanielWagner A lot of ways. In what way is it?

Answer (score 3):

You can ask GHC where it thinks a module comes from (*if* you have a package already installed providing that module).

```
% ghc-pkg find-module Data.Maybe
/usr/local/lib/ghc-8.2.2/package.conf.d
    base-4.10.1.0
/home/dmwit/.ghc/x86_64-linux-8.2.2/package.conf.d
    (no packages)
```

You can probably cook up a few quick scripts to automate calling this and cover 99.9% of the code people actually write. You might also like to abuse [graphmod](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/graphmod) -- use it to create a module graph, then ignore all the structure of the graph and just iterate over the list of module names it discovers for you and call `ghc-pkg` on each.

...but it's probably going to be much quicker to just delete `MissingH` from the dependencies in your cabal file (you *are* using a build tool like stack or cabal, right??) and see which imports GHC complains about.

Comment: No that sports as soon as the first failed import is encountered.

Comment: @orome Sure. Then you can just delete that import, stub out any functions you used from it with `undefined`, and proceed. Even with the manual effort it may be quicker than creating and debugging scripts to call `ghc-pkg`.

Comment: A bit tedious, but yes, that would work. Kida fails to fall under "do this programmatically" though.

Comment: @orome I'm a bit at a loss about what more you want. I've given both a programmatic approach and a pragmatic approach. Up to you which side of the tradeoff you decide on, but complaining that I've ignored the existence of a tradeoff seems weird to me.

Comment: @DanielWagner Do you really need to stub out the functions? I would assume that GHC checks all imports before scope-checking any variables.

Comment: @JonasDuregård If you want GHC to proceed past the scope error introduced by deleting the import to check dependent modules for import problems, then yes, you need to stub out the functions.

Comment: But why would you want that? At that point you have found all the modules from the package. I suppose if you want to check other modules, one option seems to be the `fdefer-out-of-scope-variables` option.

Comment: @JonasDuregård No, you have misunderstood. Think of this scenario: I am developing library L with modules A and B that both import modules from MissingH, and module B imports module A. Now I delete MissingH from L's dependencies and ask cabal to build L. It builds A, and notices that a MissingH import is missing. So I delete that missing import from A. But I have not yet discovered which imports in B are from MissingH, because it has not yet been built, because A has not yet been built. So I must first make A finish building -- by stubbing out anything A imported from MissingH with undefined.

Comment: @DanielWagner That is what I meant by "if you want to check other modules". `-fdefer-out-of-scope-variables` should save you from stubbing out the functions (but I have never tested the option).

Answer (score 3):

If the packages are in Stackage, you can check the module list for a snapshot to get the `Map ModuleName [PackageName]` correspondence. Yes, a module name may appear in multiple packages per snapshot. Here's an example listing:

https://www.stackage.org/lts-12.12/docs